# Time of system startup in python

Tags: python, windows

I'm working on a Windows application  that will show time when my system was started. I tried to do something with WMI, I took SystemUpTime, but it gave me time since last startup. I am looking for first startup per day, so for example if user will turn on computer at 7:00 and later will do restart at 9:00 it should still show 7:00. Is there any library which can be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a library that would do this.

One option would be to:

1. Make your program run on startup.
2. Save the boot time each time your program runs
3. Display the earliest boot time for the current day.

Save the boot times in sqlite3, its built in to Python these days.